# Comparing two data frames with the same column and row names

Tags: r

I have two data frames with the same column and row names but have different values.

```
>data_tls

plot_id    max   min   mean   std   vol
mf20       20.04 2.23  8.4     3.45 201
mf21       25.24 3.4   4.3     5.5  304
mf22       28.34 5.3   6.2     2.45 240
mf23       30.4  2.05  10.4    6.06 403

>data_uls

plot_id    max   min   mean   std   vol
mf20       19.09 4.22  6.2     4.45 220
mf21       20.2  2.6   5.3     4.5  305
mf22       32.3  4.3   2.2     3.45 255
mf23       28.4  3.05  8.05    5.85 386
```

I want to compare the values in these datasets and select the values with more than 20% different. I am trying to use compareDF package example here :https://www.r-bloggers.com/comparing-dataframes-in-r-using-comparedf/.

```
compareData <- compare_df(data_tls, data_uls, c("Plot_name"))
compareData$comparison_df
```

However, `print(compareData$html_output)` returns `Null`.
I would really appreciate if someone kindly help to solve this or would recommend any other solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example will make it easier to help

Answer (score 0):

To get a TRUE/FALSE (logical) matrix use

```
res <- data_tls > data_uls * 1.2 | data_tls < data_uls * 0.8
```

Note: The `data.frame`s may contain only numerical columns so you have to remove eg. the `plot_id` column (or select only the numerical columns in the above expression)!

You can the sum the differences via counting rows or columns like

```
rowSums(res)
colSums(res)
```